# Unable to create xpath Expression with multiple condition

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file which contain the data and I have to make XPath expression that fulfills some condition. Please help me into that.
Here are the condition: 
a. Years in Organization >=5
b.Overall Performance rating >=5
or
c. Years in Organization >=7
d.Overall Performance rating<5
and
e. City should be NY and state should be New York.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
        <LastName>Patil</LastName>
        <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
       <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
        <Address>
            <City>Bangalore</City>
            <State>Karnataka</State>
            <Zip>560212</Zip>
         </Address>
         <Years>6</Years>
         <Performance>8</Performance>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>Rahul</FirstName>
        <LastName>Dev</LastName>
        <ContactNo>9912345688</ContactNo>
        <Email>rahuldev@xyz.com</Email>
        <Address>
            <City>Mumbai</City>
            <State>Maharashtra</State>
            <Zip>400076</Zip>
        </Address>
        <Years>4</Years>
        <Performance>8</Performance>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

Comment: Your xml doesn't have anyone meeting those conditions (nobody is from NYC).

Comment: Actually it is not complete xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Modified to reflect Michael Kay's comment below:

Try this with someone in the database that does meet all conditions:

```
//*[(Years>=5 and Performance>=5) or (Years>=7 and Performance<5)][Address[City='Bangalore' and State='Larnataka']]
```

This selects the first employee.

Comment: The expression `//City/text()` should be `.//City/text()`, or better still, `.//City`; and similarly for `//State/text()`. Better still, in case an employee can have more than one address, use the predicate `[Address[City='Bangalore' and State='Larnataka']]`

Comment: @MichaelKay - OP didn't mention the concept of more than one address, but it's obviously possible. And the other comments are certainly well taken. I'll update the answer shortly.